# Expectations of outcomes

Tags: expectation

$X_1, X_2, \ldots,X_{50}$ represents the 50 outcomes of 50 independent fair coin flips. $$P(X_i=0)=P(X_i=1)=0.5$$ I am trying to analyze the different possibilities of $\operatorname{E}(X)$ and $\operatorname{var}(X)$. Define $X$ to be $X = X_1 - X_2.$ For instance, why would the answers for $\operatorname{E}(X_1)$ and $\operatorname{E}(X)$ be different? Similarly for $\operatorname{var}(X_1)$ and $\operatorname{var}(X)$. My confusion stems how to even interpret $\operatorname{E}(X_1)$. Does it mean what is the probability of getting the same outcome as $X_1$? and if so, how would I interpret $\operatorname{E}(X)$?

Comment: What's $X$? You have $X_i$ defined but not $X$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Expectation is linear, i.e.
\begin{align}
E[aX+bY] = aE[X]+bE[Y].
\end{align}

Since $X_i$ are independent then it follows 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[aX_1+bX_2] = a^2\operatorname{Var}X_1+b^2\operatorname{Var}X_{2}.
\end{align}

Comment: that still doesn't clarify my confusion. Can you please expand on that?